# How to create a getQueryResults job in BigQuery with no timeout?

Tags: google-bigquery

The BigQuery [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#running_asynchronous_queries) for querying data with asynchronous jobs using the Java API says that we do not need to poll for the result if we call `jobs.getQueryResults(jobId)` with no timeout. However, there is a default timeout of 10 seconds according to the Jobs documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/getQueryResults).

My question is what is the way to call `getQueryResults` with no timeout. Should I put an extremely large number as a timeout parameter or the parameter there should be probably 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "no timeout" do you mean waiting forever?

The underlying infrastructure (Google API frontend) used by BigQuery does not permit connections of unlimited duration. Your best bet is to set a reasonable timeout value and retry when you get a timeout.

This is likely a good best practice anyway, since things like network hiccups can cause errors in the request, and by retrying the `getQueryResults` operation you will be able to get the results without having to re-run the query.